# Why isn't accepted the root address in "href" attribute in "link" tag on html head

Tags: php, html

I can't use the root address to refer to styles file  in link tag on html head.

I have an html code , when I put this address into href in link tag in head section, The styles work correctly

plaintext

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css">
```

,but when I put the root of address ,The styles aren't read

plaintext

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/xampp/htdocs/7Learn.php/7auth.php/assets/css/styles.css">
```

I try different directory and I know that the directory must be started from current directory .

but I want to use the root address because I have a constant in php as BASE_PATH(

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/7Learn.php/7auth.php/
```

)  and I want to use that for all directory .

Is there a way to  solve it .

I will be very grateful for your help, friends.

Comment: An href should be a URL, not a filesystem path. If you start your links with a forward slash, then the links will be absolute from the root of the project, if you don't, then it is relative and will look from the folder you are in. I prefer to always use an absolute href.

Comment: `assets/css/styles.css` is served from your (XAMPP) webserver. Your "root" address is a link directly to a file on your local machine. Websites can't directly access files on your local machine because that would be a huge security risk.

Comment: `C:/xampp/htdocs/7Learn.php/7auth.php/assets/css/styles.css"` is not a correct path for a local file. Besides, if you use a XAMPP webserver, use the address of that webserver.

Comment: @delboy1978uk
thanks a lot , I changed BASE_PATH to BASE_URL(localhost/myProject) AND start its rest by forward slash . It worked correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot for all, I am a beginner here , hope you will be more success

Comment: @peyman parsaei glad i could help! best of luck with your programming